# S-<right> (org-agenda-do-date-later) is mapped to windmove-right

Tags: key-bindings, org-agenda

I moved to a new machine with my identical emacs configuration and all of a sudden `S-<right>` (which used to work as `org-agenda-do-date-later`) is responding bound to the command `windmove-right` (found in `windmove-mode-map`), which is an autoloaded interactive
byte-compiled Lisp function in ‘windmove.el’. How to make this keybinding work again on `org-agenda` as it is supposed to?

Comment: Is `windmove-mode-map` a minor-mode map? Minor-mode maps override major-mode maps. See the question I pointed to as a possible duplicate, for what to do when both are minor-mode maps. You can also just unbind that key in `windmove-mode-map` (i.e., bind it to `nil`).

Comment: So, if you are in the Org mode agenda and you say `C-h c S-<right>`, Emacs tells you that the key is bound to `windmove-right`? And just to make sure: `S-<right>` means "press the Super key and while keeping it pressed, press the right-arrow key" - is that correct?

Comment: The reason I'm asking is that on the new computer, `S-<right>` might be hijacked by your desktop environment, so it never gets to Emacs, but it may be doing some "window" action that you are misinterpreting as `windmove-right`. So I am trying to make sure that we are not chasing phantoms by confirming *how* exactly you found out that the key is misbound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not yet add a comment, so I wrote an answer.
It seams you have enabled windmove-mode and you have called the function windmove-default-keybindings. You can get help as usual with describe-function (C-h f). I have no idea why you only have these mappings on one system and not the other.